# Quick layover in San Andres Airport

Tags: air-travel, airports, layovers, colombia

I will be flying from Bogota (BOG) via San Andres (ADZ) to Providencia (PVA) on separate tickets. According to schedule, there will be a layover of about 4 hours (11:56 - 16:00).

Assuming that the inbound flight is on time, will it be possible (and reasonable) to leave the airport to see/do something on the island? If so, are there any recommendations?

I will have a similar situation (08:50 - 13:59, so ~5h) on my way back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how are you traveling with, but in general, I would visit the [Blow Hole](https://www.sanandrescolombia.com.co/en/tours/blow-hole/) or I would go to [La Regata](http://www.restaurantelaregatta.com/) which is one of the best restaurants on the island with a perfect view of the sea.

It will be lunch time so eating is a nice alternative, however, the **Blow Hole** is a natural spot that I really like, it's on the other side of the island from the airport but it's a small so it's only a 35 minutes ride from one side to the other.

Beaches are also nice, just remember, it's a small island, there is a marathon around the island, the winners last around 3.5 hours